Mouse invisible on GTK window
Simple GUI app developed using GTK3.0 missing the mouse trail
I wrote a simple GUI app developed using GTK3.0 running on XOrg X server with Mali framebuffer device shared object library as the graphics backend. The mouse does not show up anywhere on the window when I launch XOrg (with no window manager which is understandable) but when I launch the app (full screen mode), the mouse click is registered if the mouse is on a button for example (I handle the button event). I would like to know if mouse display is possible with GTK 3.0.
I have tried a few things like setting all pointer event masks but with no success:
gtk_widget_set_events(window,GDK_POINTER_MOTION_MASK|GDK_EXPOSURE_MASK|GDK_POINTER_MOTION_HINT_MASK|GDK_BUTTON_MOTION_MASK);
Whats funny is If I launch an instance of ffplay to display streamed content from my webcam anywhere on the screen, the mouse shows up (a cross hair) and the pointer tracks mouse movement and remains functional even after terminating ffplay.
I traced their output device code and saw its calling SDL_ShowCursor -> SDL_ShowCursor -> SDL_ShowCursor-> DirectFB_ShowCursor / DirectFB_MoveCursor - Thats where I kinda got stuck, looks like DirectFB_MoveCursor implementation is empty in SDL code, and the Direct_FBShowCursor is seems to be drawing mouse pointers with directFB. Does anybody know why Xorg wont show the mouse at the first place?
Thanks
